# How do I use my own header names in a DataGridView filled by database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sqlite

I'm trying to use my own headers text in a DataGridView which is filled automatically from database. I've tried `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` then do something like to create the columns:

```
    void createSearchResultHeader()
    {
        foreach(var prop in typeof(DB.Message).GetProperties())
        {
            var display =
               typeof(DB.Message)
               .GetProperty(prop.Name)
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), inherit: false)
               .FirstOrDefault() as System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute;
            DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            col.HeaderText = display.DisplayName;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        }
    }
```

then load the results with:

```
            using (var conn = createConnection())
            using (var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand(conn)))
            using (var dt = new DataSet())
            {
                dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                da.Fill(dt);
                dg.DataSource = dt.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
```

The issue is, with `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` the columns are created (I call `createSearchResultHeader()` on Form's load) but the result from database are empty but if I change `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true` the results from database are loaded successfully but it add its own columns rather use the ones created by `createSearchResultHeader()`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
void createSearchResultHeader()
{
    foreach(var prop in typeof(DB.Message).GetProperties())
    {
        var display =
           typeof(DB.Message)
           .GetProperty(prop.Name)
           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), inherit: false)
           .FirstOrDefault() as System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute;
        DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = display.DisplayName;
        col.DataPropertyName = prop.Name; // Add this
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! So simple! Thank you :)